# api.py:87: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, concatenation

I hope to generate a DataDrame which is used to train a random forest by calling:

```
stats_cpu_primitive=pd.concat([stats_user['datetime'], dayofweek, stats_user['user_value'], stats_system['system_value'], stats_wait['wait_value'], stats_nice['nice_value'], stats_interrupt['interrupt_value'], stats_softirq['softirq_value'], stats_steal['steal_value'], stats_idle['idle_value']], axis=1)
```

Then I got:

> D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py:87: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
>     result = result.union(other)
>   D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py:57: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
>     union = _union_indexes(indexes)

Correspondingly, the elements in the column of dayofweek are all **nan**. 
But **I have not conduct any "compare" related operation**. I conduct .dtype, dayofweek.dtype is float64, stats_user['datetime'].dtype is str, the left are all int64. However, even though I conduct astype() to transfer stats_user['datetime'].dtype and dayofweek to be int64, I got the same result.

How to deal with it? Many thanks.

Comment: What is the value of your display environment variable on the server? (echo $DISPLAY)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get ":3" while type: echo $DISPLAY. This issue has been disturbing me. @TocToc